# Carregamento de site extremamente lento em WordPres

Tags: wordpress

Depois de diversos testes e agora sem saber mais o que fazer, resolvi recorrer a essa comunidade para que vocês possam tentar me ajudar.

Estou desenvolvendo o site de uma cliente em WordPress. O endereço é [www.marylindemuth.com.br](http://www.marylindemuth.com.br). Ele está hospedado no plano Premium da Hostinger. Tenho o site de uma outra cliente hospedado no Hostinger também, inclusive, no plano gratuito, e nesse outro site o problema não está se apresentando.

Eis o que acontece: o site (Mary Lindemuth) está extremamente lento, tanto o frontend quanto o backend. Assim, imagino que não seja nenhum problema causado por plugins ou pelo tema, uma vez que os mesmos não são carregados quando acessamos a interface administrativa do WordPress, certo?

Mesmo assim, eu fiz um teste desativando todos os plugins, um por um, para tentar identificar se um deles estava provocando a lentidão no carregamento do site. De nada adiantou. Também tentei trocar o tema e ainda assim não resolveu.

Imaginei, então, que o problema estava no servidor. Entrei em contato com a Hostinger e eles responderam que não há nada de errado do lado deles e que, sim, o problema era de otimização do meu site e que provavelmente eu estava fazendo mal uso do WordPress com o uso excessivo de plugins e widgets.

Porém, se vocês acessarem o site (tenham paciência, pois está muito lento mesmo), verão que ele é bastante simples e não pode estar consumindo tantos recursos assim. Tenho apenas 8 plugins instalados e ativos enquanto em outros sites de outros clientes também hospedados no Hostinger tenho mais de 20 plugins e a lentidão não se apresenta.

Gostaria muito de pedir que vocês me ajudem a tentar identificar o que pode estar causando essa lentidão. Fiz um teste com o Pingdom e o load time foi de 60 segundos. Para mim, geralmente demora até mais do que isso para carregar.

De acordo com a experiência de vocês, o que pode estar acontecendo?

Agradeço desde já!

Giovanna

Answer (score 2):

dei uma olhada no google pagespeed, ele sugere que você compacteas as imagens ultilizadas no site, bem como os arquivos javascript. outra coisa poderia chamar a webfont do google no footer para não bloquear o carregamento da pagina. em ultima estancia recomendo ainstalação de um plugin de cache segue alguns links que podem te dar uma luz:

https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/

projeto que mostra como melhorar o teu carregamento no browser:

http://browserdiet.com/pt/

Answer (score 0):

Olá, seu site está hospedado em um host fraco, acrédite, eu usei ele, e sei como é, ele tem uma demora de resposta muito grande, mas não é só isso, ele tem falta de: `GZip`, `Cache`, `Compactação Js`, `Compactação de CSS`, `Compactação de Imagens` e `Compactação de HTML`.

Agora vamos lá, como resolver isso, é bem simples:

Primeiro, pense em trocar de host ou dar uma reclamação na sua Hospedagem.

Segundo, baixe o W3 Total Cache(https://wordpress.org/plugins/w3-total-cache/), nele você pode ativar o GZip, Compactar HTML,JS,Imagens e CSS.

Terceiro, baixe o WP Smush.it(https://br.wordpress.org/plugins/wp-smushit/) e ative a compactação de imagens, configure como deseja, se não me engano eles tem versão em Português Brasileiro.

Outra coisa que pode ajudar, comece a usar CDN's, alguns são pagos, mas tem uns gratuitos, o WP Smush.it e o W3 Total Cache tem compatibilidade com CDN's, use que isso vai melhorar MUITO na velocidade do site.

Caso não queira ou não consiga usar o W3 Total Cache, o wordpress tá com um Plugin chamado WP Super Cache(https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-super-cache/) que é excelente e ajuda MUITO no site, e tem muitas opções, recomendo usar o PingDom(http://tools.pingdom.com/fpt/) para ver a velocidade do seu site, e o PageSpeed Insights do Google(https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/) para ver a qualidade do seu site.

Boa sorte.

Answer (score -1):

Penso que o problema não deverá ser causado por plugins e widgets, eu entrei no Website e demorou apenas 2 segundos a entrar, entrei novamente e fiz esse processo 3 vezes, nenhuma das vezes o website estava lento. 
Tomei a liberdade de ir à parte do link de **/wp-admins** para ver se o painel estava lento e também não achei que estivesse lento também. 
Segundo isto penso que o problema será mesmo de uma incompatibilidade sua com o website, sugiro que experimente a aceder ao mesmo através de outra internet, por vezes existem incompatibilidades directas com certos sites, poderá ser esse o caso.

Também sugiro que deixe passar 48 horas, porque poderá ser alguma atualização ou algum sub-carregamento de algum servidor, algo que a hostinger por vezes não consegue controlar e poderá acontecer, nesse caso basta aguardar um pouco.